# C++ Lua (table of table of objects)

Tags: c++, scripting, lua

I want to convert a vector of vector of objects to a table of table of objects in Lua.

So I have a simple script in lua :

```
objects = getObjects()
explosion = objects[1][1]:getDestructible()
print (explosion)
```

And this is my .cpp file

```
std::vector<std::vector<Area> > objects;
int x;
int y;

y = 0;
lua_newtable(L);
for (std::vector<std::vector<Area> >::iterator it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); ++it)
{
    lua_createtable(L, 2, 0);
    x = 0;
    for (std::vector<Area>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2)
    {
        lua_newtable(L);
        luaL_getmetatable(L, "luaL_Object");
        lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, x + 1);
        x++;
    }
    lua_rawseti(L, -2, y);
    y++;
}
```

When I run the script I always get something like "Attempt to index a nil index". Did I miss something ?

Comment: Where are you pushing the actual object onto the stack and then putting it in the inner table?

You create the outer table then create the inner tables and give them metatables but you never fill them with any contents (or is the metatable supposed to handle that access?). If that's the case are you sure the metatable is working? If you split the indexing up into steps which step fails?

Comment: Yep, the metatable contain all the desire method I'd like to use I'm pretty sure it work, cause it use to work for a simple list of vector. I'm not sure about how can I test which step fail ? I mean Isn't it just an issue with the index ?

Comment: @Alex: Still your Lua stack isn't balanced in the inner loop: You  push one value (`luaL_getmetatable`), then pop one value (`lua_setmetatable`), and then pop another value (`lua_rawseti`). You are probably missing a `lua_newtable` or a `lua_newuserdata` before the `luaL_getmetatable`. Also the stack index in the last `lua_rawseti` should probably be `-2`.

Comment: @siffiejoe: I've adjust my code above considering, what you were saying, but I'm a bit lost, I also try print(type(objects[1])) which give me nil, so the first index doesn't work ... any idea ?!

Comment: There might be an off-by-one error for the outter `lua_rawseti(L, -2, y);
    y++;` compared to your inner `lua_rawseti(L, -2, x + 1); x++;`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your help ! I've finally found the answer to my question, this is it :

```
int Lua::luaGetObjects(lua_State *L)
{
    int x;
    int y;

    y = 0;
    lua_newtable(L);
    for (std::vector<std::vector<Area> >::iterator it2 = objects.begin(); it2 != objects.end(); ++it2)
    {
        x = 0;
        lua_newtable(L);
        for (std::vector<Area>::iterator it = it2->begin(); it != it2->end(); it++, x++) 
        {

            lua_pushnumber(L, x);

            luaL_getmetatable(L, "luaL_Object");
            lua_setmetatable(L, -2);

            lua_rawseti(L, -2, x + 1);
            x++;
        }
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, y + 1);
        y++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

With which I can call finally call :

```
objects = getObjects()
explosion = objects[1][1]:getExplosion()
print(explosion)
```

Comment: What happens if  you execute `objects = getObjects(); print( (0):getExplosion() )`, and is the result of `objects[1][1]:getExplosion()` identical to `objects[2][1]:getExplosion()`?

Comment: @siffiejoe: Hey, I experimented the issue your certainly talk about with the first index :/ Do you know how to catch it ? Anyway I completely change my algorythm by just setting a metatable with all my cpp getter in it, they take two parameters that I can finally catch with `luaL_checknumber(L, 2)` and `luaL_checknumber(L, 3)` so now I call `objects:getExplosion(x, y)`
I guess it's more efficiant to create only one object instead of a table of table of objects. Everything work perfectly now, thank you again !

Comment: All numbers in Lua share a common metatable, so when you set a metatable on `x` in the inner loop, all numbers suddenly have your methods available. That's why `(0):getExplosion()` works. Also the value at `objects[1][1]` and `objects[2][1]` is `0` in both cases, so the method call `getExplosion()` should return identical results (the same result as `(0):getExplosion()` actually). Your new approach is much better.